# How to correspond random numbers with a certain string?

Tags: c#, string, random, int

I generate my random numbers with the `Random num1 = new Random()` method. I wanted to know if there was any way to have something like 10 different questions, each corresponding to a possible number. For example, when the random number 1 is generated, I want the question "What is the fastest animal?". I was able to do this quite easily, but every time I did the `Console.ReadLine();` right afterward, the question before that changes on me. An example of what this would look like is this:

`What is the fastest animal? >` and then once I answered, it would show something like this: 
`An elephant's diet consists mostly of what? cheetah`. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

````
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] incorrectAnswersJediSimple = new string[5];
        Random JediS1 = new Random();
        int randJediS1 = JediS1.Next(1, 4);
        int totalScore = 0;
        string JediQ11 = "JediQ11";
        switch(randJediS1){

            case 1:
                JediQ11 = "Who is Luke Skywalker's father?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ111 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (JediQ111.Equals("Darth Vader", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ111.Equals("Vader", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ111.Equals("Anakin Skywalker", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ111.Equals("Anakin", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))                                                                               {
                totalScore++;
                } else {
                incorrectAnswersJediSimple[0] = "#1";
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                JediQ11 = "Who is Luke Skywalker's sister?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ112 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (JediQ112.Equals("Princess Leia", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ112.Equals("Leia", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ112.Equals("Leia Organa", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ112.Equals("Leia Skywalker", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ112.Equals("Princess Leia Organa", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ112.Equals("Princess Leia Skywalker", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))                                                                               {
                totalScore++;
                } else {
                incorrectAnswersJediSimple[0] = "#1";
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                JediQ11 = "What is Darth Vaders real name?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ113 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (JediQ113.Equals("Anakin Skywalker", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ113.Equals("Anakin", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ113.Equals("Ani boi", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || JediQ113.Equals("ani", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))                                                                               {
                totalScore++;
                } else {
                incorrectAnswersJediSimple[0] = "#1";
                }

                break;
            case 4:
                JediQ11 = "What species is Admiral Ackbar?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ114 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 5:
                JediQ11 = "Who is Han Solo's Wookie sidekick?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ115 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 6:
                JediQ11 = "What species is Jar Jar Binks?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ116 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 7:
                JediQ11 = "On what planet does Luke first find Yoda in the original trilogy?  ";
                Console.WriteLine(JediQ11);
                string JediQ117 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 8:
                JediQ11 = "Who is Rey's grandfather?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ118 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 9:
                JediQ11 = "Who threw Mace Windu out of a window?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ119 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 10:
                JediQ11 = "What planet is Jedi Master Plo Koon from?  ";
                Console.Write(JediQ11);
                string JediQ1110 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            default:
                JediQ11 = "ERROR";
                Console.WriteLine(JediQ11);
                Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
                string ERROR11 = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            }

    }
}```
````

Comment: Please show us your code. Without it, there is no way to help you.

Comment: @Christopher Ok, there you go. Hope this helps!

Comment: You got a ton of repeating code inside those cases, that can be seperated out into a function. There is also no loop that will actually keep generating random numbers and keep asking questions. Your description has 0 relation to the code you showed. Go back and start with something simpler, like a basic toutorial. This project is way beyond your current skill level. | There is just too much I would need to fix or asume, to turn this into working code.